# Merging appsettings with environment variables in .NET Core

Tags: docker, .net-core, environment-variables, config

I am running a .NET Core app in Docker (in Kubernetes), passing environment variables to the Docker container and using them in my app.

In my .NET Core app I have the following C# class:

```cs
public class EnvironmentConfiguration
{
    public string EXAMPLE_SETTING { get; set; }
    public string MY_SETTING_2 { get; set; }
}
```

And I setup my `appsettings` as such:

```cs
config.
    AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").
    AddJsonFile($"appsettings.docker.json", true).
    AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

DI setup:

```cs
services.Configure<EnvironmentConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

And in my Controller I use it as such:

```cs
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/my")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<EnvironmentConfiguration> _environmentConfiguration;

    public MyController(IOptions<EnvironmentConfiguration> environmentConfiguration)
    {
        _environmentConfiguration = environmentConfiguration;
    }
}
```

I run docker:

```
docker run -p 4000:5000 --env-file=myvariables
```

The file `myvariables` looks like this:

```
EXAMPLE_SETTING=example!!!
MY_SETTING_2=my-setting-2!!!!
```

This works. I can use my `_environmentConfiguration` and see that my variables are set.

However... I would like to merge environment variables with appsettings so that the values from appsettings are used as fallback when environment variables are not found. Somehow merging these two lines:

```cs
services.Configure<EnvironmentConfiguration>(settings => Configuration.GetSection("EnvironmentConfiguration").Bind(settings));
services.Configure<EnvironmentConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

Is this somehow possible?

My fallback plan is to inherit from the `EnvironmentConfiguration` class and use a separate DI to have two separate configurations injected and then merge them "manually" in code but this solution is undesirable.

Comment: I am looking into achieving something like this, @Marcus, would you be able to add dockerfile to the question for my reference? It would be nice if you could 2 versions, with env file and with env separately listed. Many thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```cs
config.
    AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").
    AddJsonFile("appsettings.docker.json", true).
    AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

is actually enough to override appsettings values using environment variables.

Let's say you have the following in your appsettings.json file;

```json
{
  "Logging": {
      "Level": "Debug"
  }
}
```

you can override value of `Logging.Level` by setting the environment variable named `Logging:Level` to the value of your preference.

Be aware that `:` is used to specify nested properties in environment variable keys.

**Also note: from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?tabs=basicconfiguration#simple-configuration);**

> **If a colon (:) can't be used in environment variable names on your system, replace the colon (:) with a double-underscore (__).**

Comment: Double  underscore really solved my problem with environment variables in docker

Comment: Double underscore is really the way to go... also when deploying in azure container instances where you want to pass nested configuration values.

Comment: Does the order of this chain affect which source takes precedence? If we were to rearrange the code above to `config.AddEnvironmentVariables().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddJsonFile($"appsettings.docker.json", true);`, would values present in `appsettings.docker.json` take priority over values in the other two sources since it was called last?

Comment: I've just been caught out by ordering - put `AddEnvironmentVariables()` as the last call or it doesn't work!!!

Comment: Could you add an example of appsettings file and dockerfile for completeness? That will help people (like me) understand the actual setup easily. It would be great if you could add a docker command example showing how to run that image with setting a variable. Thanks