# .Net Core appsettings.json best practices - override dev settings (or vice versa)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Looking for a sensible approach in regards to structuring appsettings.json files in .Net Core.

Should the base 'appsettings.json' file be configured for running in a dev environment, and then environment based overrides such as appsettings.production.json overwrite specific keys for production?

Or should appsettings.json only contain config that is shared across ALL environments, and then a specific appsettings.development/staging.json file used to explicitly set keys for those environments?

My concern is - say an app is deployed to a live server, but a key stored in an environment variable (e.g. to override connection string) is missing or spelt wrong etc. In this case the app would fall back to the base appsettings.json connection string which would be the incorrect DB for the live environment. A scenario like this sounds pretty disasterous, particularly as this could easily go unnoticed?

So really the question boils down to - should the contents of the base appsettings.json file be 'dev' values as default (e.g. dev DBs, sandbox APIs) that are overridden with production data, or vice versa?

Comment: Your question is quite good, but it surely invites debates of what is the best way to base the `appsettings.json` into development activity. Please focus more on what your problem, instead of asking what strategy you should choose when dealing with `appsettings.json`. Therefore a good question on SO should avoid opinions as answers.

Comment: FYI: Check your `Properties > launchSettings.json` to find the corresponding commands for launching profiles using the specified settings from `appsettings`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few principals come into play here:

First, any broken/missing items should error out vs. silently work in some subset of cases. This is valuable because it uncovers issues early on in development. Only put values in the base file that are constant across environments or will reveal missing values when not overridden e.g. under test. This enables you to write negative test cases to a known value, which can help uncover errors in more complex configurations.

Second, any extra deployed content is added risk so deploy nothing extra. Put the appropriate values for each environment into the environment-specific file and nothing else. These values should override the base file, enabling you to deploy and run without manual intervention. Use the out-of-box configuration loader to load (only) the correct file for the current environment.

Third, it can be helpful to have a way to override values in the environment without re-deploying any files. The value here depends on your environment and situation e.g. security event. As a result, environment variables should override the preceding two sources.

If you're using a centralized configuration source, can you allow a deployed file to override it? This is a dev-sec-ops/policy question. Your answer will determine where centralized config should fall in the list. The farther down you put it the more likely your developers will need to run an instance locally.

There may be other considerations or additional layers that make sense in your project. The important thing is to have a "why" for the choices you make, and to be able to explain and justify them logically in your context.

Answer (score 12):

UPDATE: I wanted to append to this that I no longer use Azure App Configuration, only the KeyVault. I was disappointed that the pricing allows for 1 free AppConfig per subscription, and then appears to charge more than 1.20$CDN a day for each beyond the first. Which for me meant an extra 36$ a month for something that will only be used once a day (assuming I let the web app wind down at night). The price point just doesn't make any sense whatsoever. I'd just as soon use multiple KeyVault, as their cost looks to be purely based on usage, and at a pittance per thousands of transactions. I don't understand what the intended use case for AppConfig is to justify its price point.

---

I've gotten to the habit storing my configuration in Azure under an AzureAppConfig and/or an AzureKeyVault. It gives me a central location to manage my dev, staging/test, production settings to and doesn't require me to complicate my deployment with manipulating appsettings files, or storing in them in some sort of deployment repo. It's really only ever read from azure when the application starts (I didn't need to be able to refresh them while my app was running). That being said, it made it a little interesting for the local dev story because I personally wanted the order of operations to be `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.{environment}.json`, `AzureAppConfig`, `KeyVault`, then finally `secrets.json`. That way, no matter what, I could override a setting from azure with my local secrets file (even if the setting I was overriding wasn't technically a secret).

I basically ended up writing some custom code in `program.cs` to handle loading the config sources from Azure, then finish with looking for the `JsonConfigurationSource` that had a `Path` of `"secrets.json"`, then bump that to be the last item in my `IConfigurationBuilder.Sources`.

For me, my files get used as follows

- `appsettings.json` - Common settings that would need to be set for any environment, and will *likely* never change depending on the environment.
  `appsettings.{environment}.json` - Mostly just en empty JSON files that basically just name the `AzureAppConfig` & `AzuerKeyVault` resource names to connect to
- `AzureAppConfig` - Basically for anything that would be different between Production, Staging/Testing, or local Development, AND is not a sensitive piece of information. API endpoints addresses, IP addresses, various URLs, error logging information, that sort of thing.
- `AzureKeyVault` - Anything sensitive. Usernames, passwords, keys for external APIs (auth, license keys, connection strings, etc).

The thing is, even if you put a setting in `appsettings.json`, that doesn't mean you can't override it with `appsettings.{enviroment}.json` or somewhere else. I've frequently put a settings in the root setting file with a value of `NULL`, just to remind me that it's a setting used in the app. So a better question might be, do you want to be able to run your app (as in no errors) with nothing but the base `appsettings.json` and `secrets.json`? Or would the contents from `appsettings.{enviroment}.json` always be needed to successfully spin up?

The other thing to look at based off of your question is validation for your configuration. Later versions of `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` offer various ways to validate your options so that you can try and catch instances where something was left empty/undefined. I typically decorate my POCO Options classes with data annotation attributes and then use `ValidateDataAnnotations()` to verify they get setup correctly.

For example

```
services.AddOptions<MailOptions>().Bind(configuration.GetSection("MailSettings")).ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

It's worth noting this validation runs only when you try to request something like the `MailOptions` I use as an example above, from DI (so not at startup)
For this reason, I also created your my own `IStartupFilter` to preemptively request one or more of my Options classes from the service provider when the app starts up, in order to force that same Validation to run before the app even starts accepting requests.

```
public class EagerOptionsValidationStartupFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    public readonly ICollection<Type> EagerValidateTypes = new List<Type>();
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public EagerOptionsValidationStartupFilter(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        foreach (var eagerType in EagerValidateTypes)
        {
            dynamic test = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOptions<>).MakeGenericType(eagerType));
            _ = test.Value;
        }

        return next;
    }
}
```

`startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter>(x =>
        new EagerOptionsValidationStartupFilter(x)
        {
            EagerValidateTypes = {
                typeof(MailOptions),
                typeof(OtherOptions),
                typeof(MoreImportantOptions)
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Hey Nick, what would be the best place/method to store the Azure App Config endpoint?

Answer (score 11):

I think this has the boring answer; it depends. But my favorite approach is this:

```
appsetting.json (base settings)
appsettings.development.json (dev with no secrets)
appsettings.production.json (production with no secrets)
```

Appsettings where the values that are secret only exist in the base setting while the other are written in the respective appsettings.[env].json. So example database connection key only exists in base setting with the local database. It´s the environments job to replace it

Example for database connection and logging

appsettings.json

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
  “dbConnection: “data source=localhost” <—— only here
},
“environment”: “local”,
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": “Verbose”
  }
},
}
```

appsettings.development.json

```
{
“environment”: “development”,
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": “Warning”
  }
},
}
```

appsettings.production.json

```
{
“environment”: “production”,
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": “Information”
  }
},
}
```

> My concern is - say an app is deployed to a live server, but a key
>   stored in an environment variable (e.g. to override connection string)
>   is missing or spelt wrong etc. In this case the app would fall back to
>   the base appsettings.json connection string which would be the
>   incorrect DB for the live environment. A scenario like this sounds
>   pretty disasterous, particularly as this could easily go unnoticed?

You can always do this. But some sanity tests should do it. Do a simple health check where you ping the database if your infrastructure / deploy pipeline allows it.

Comment: In a PROD environment where it has to be right (e.g. medical, finance, etc.) it is often better/safer to fail when mis-configured than to allow a "fall back" to some other value.

Comment: This is exactly my situation - I just don't feel like it's acceptable to ever have a scenario where you could 'fall back' to development envs or anything like that...

Comment: Alright! Then you should remove appsetting.json and only have appsettings,[env].json files. But still, you are not safe because you might build using the wrong environment variable. The best way to prevent this is to have 1) automatic build, then you really just need to have it right one time. 2) Make sure only production services can connect to production databases and other services in the infrastructure. 3) Don´t have connection details to production services in source code. These should be injected when deploying production service.

Comment: True about the env var, but its more likely to be missing than wrong (and if missing defaults to production anyway).

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways how to shape your settings (thats the beauty of .NET Core). The way how I normally do it, is the following:

```
appsetting.json (template)
appsettings.development.json (dev with no secrets)
```

I actually do not put any settings in appsettings.json. I use it as a template map of the settings that must (can) be set during deployment.

```
// appsettings.json

{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "dbConnection": "************************"
  },
  "environment": "************************",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "************************"
    }
  },
}
```

That way if I miss any setting, it will become apparent later on that it was forgotten. I dont have to worry about accidentally using settings that "slipped" through the hierarchy. Therefore if you look at your other jsons, they are complete and there are no hidden settings.

```
// appsettings.Development.json

{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "dbConnection": "data source=localhost"
  },
  "environment": "local",
  "Logging": {
     "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose"
    }
  }
}
```

Sharing settings seems to be a good idea for small applications. It actually gives more problems if your application gets more complex.

Answer (score 2):

I've started to get rid of `appsettings.json` and use, normally:

```
appsettings.local.json
appsettings.development.json
appsettings.staging.json
```

etc.

Now for running commands, I can explicitly set my environment variable with `$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="local"` or `$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="development"`

I get a clear response when I use `$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` whereas before, getting "no response" left me unsure which settings it'd be using - and I won't accidentally run other commands in the wrong environment.

You can also then set the environment variable in the launchsettings.json for running the solution.

And for deployment, you handle that with the build pipeline or make sure your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set in the web app configs

Answer (score 1):

IMO the `appsettings.json` that you commit to source control should be configured for running everything (or as much as possible) in a local dev environment. Note: sometimes there might be third party dependencies that you can't spin up locally (e.g. a third party API service that your app/service consumes) in which case I'd commit dev/sandbox values for these specific settings, but for everything else (e.g. connections to databases, message broker, idp, telemetry stack, etc), I'd configure for local. I also like to have an initialisation script to quickly spin up all the app dependencies. A microservice template that I use at the company I work uses PowerShell and docker-compose to quickly and easily spin up local containerised dependencies, so that team members can get things up and running as quickly as possible.

Here are some reasons for the above approach:

- Makes no assumptions about the existance of a persistent centralised dev/test environment, or a team members ability to access such an environment.
- No secrets and passwords in source control (or at least no production secrets and passwords).
- Allows team members to clone the repo and get up and running as quickly as possible - they don't have to go and get a bunch of appsettings from somewhere and update appsettings manually.

Couple other pointers:

- If you're using docker, you can override individual appsettings by using environment variables (using double underscore syntax described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298284/merging-appsettings-with-environment-variables-in-net-core#answer-48308126)), however this can sometimes get a bit verbose. I prefer to use environment specific override file as shown below. Note the `CONFIG_DIR` and `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment vars:

```cs
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
   {
      string basePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONFIG_DIR") ?? Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
      string environmentVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
      Console.WriteLine("Config directory: " + basePath + Environment.NewLine + "Environment: " + environmentVariable);
      builder.SetBasePath(basePath);
      builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentVariable))
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings." + environmentVariable + ".json", true, true);
      builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
   })
```

- Ideally the deployment and config management of your app/service should be in a separate git repo using something like Ansible. If any config settings change, this repo should go through the same sort of code review process as your application repo, everything is audited in the git history, and deployment is automated. In short this makes it a lot less likely to mess up a config setting.
- If you deploy to Microsoft Azure, or use Azure services; you should check out [Azure App Config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview) - basically app configuration as a service (and compatible with file based appsettings).
- If you're deploying to Linux, configuration files such as appsettings should be copied to `/etc/opt/[name-of-service]` and should not be in the same directory as the binaries under `/opt/[name-of-service]`. This follows the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf). This is what the `CONFIG_DIR` environment variable described earlier is for.
- I generally have an `appsettings.docker.json` file in SCM as well for when I want to run my app/service as a local container. An example of when I use this instead of just running the app from Visual Studio IDE, is when I want to test logging via docker logging provider.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why should environment variables be damaged during deployment? I find it more likely than during development process a change will be made to `appsettings.*.json` files that will break something.
   Also why do you need `env` variables if you're thinking about adding the same settings in your `appsettings.json` as a fallback?
2. Not only code can be tested. You can write tests for your configuration as well. That's a more robust approach comparing to configuration conventions. And if something can go wrong it can go wrong no matter in how many places you'll repeat you connection string. Actually... **if** you'll repeat your connection string you will violate DRY and you will be asking for troubles. Because these duplicates **will** diverge in time.
3. Either of your approaches should yield the same result. If `env` is broken

   1. in the first case `appsettings.json\dbConnection (dev)` will be overriden by `appsettings.production.json\dbConnection`.
   2. in the second case `dbConnection` will be taken straight from `appsettings.production.json\dbConnection` (or from `appsettings.development.json\dbConnection` on your local machine).
   3. in the third case...? Don't really understand what do you mean by "vice versa"? But if you'll put production values in `appsettings.json` they'll still be overridden by values from the respective files. Or not (if they're not there). No matter.

So, as I see it, the only question is: should there be any settings in the `appsettings.json` that are different for `prod` and `dev` environments, or should it only contain settings common for both?

And the sensible answer is: it should contain only common settings. Because it's expected. And more convenient - if you need to change a setting for `prod` or for `dev` you don't need to remember where to find them. Obviously in `appsettings.production.json` for `prod`, and in `appsettings.development.json` for `dev`. And also it's more predictable - one day, if not you, then someone else will spend some time trying to figure out why db connection fails if the connection string before his eyes **is** correct (and that's because in the middle of the night he forget to check if it was overridden).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the environment from 'Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable' I would suggest to use

> context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName

This gives more flexibility, e.g. when the ENV variable would be DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT instead of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT (and more configuration)