# Using appsettings.json with different databases

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a visual studio project, 3 people are working using different databases, so each person is keeping his own version of appsettings.json locally without pushing the file into git but sometimes we forgot and we push it causing issue on the other guys.
Is there any way to put some conditions to work all together without interfering each others?

For example, this is my file using MYDB:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MdmDb": "Server=XXX;Database=MYDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

My colleague will have the same file but db name will be different

Comment: Yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087066/net-core-appsettings-json-best-practices-override-dev-settings-or-vice-versa If you use UserSecrets, for one example, each person's personal store can override the connection string parameter at runtime.

Comment: Here's some docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Another way is to commit the config file then add it to .gitignore so future commits are ignored. Much more painful to add desired changes though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core appsettings.json best practices - override dev settings (or vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087066/net-core-appsettings-json-best-practices-override-dev-settings-or-vice-versa)

Comment: I didn't try yet, I jumped to an high issue now :(

Comment: Well I'm not sure about that, because everyone has his own connection string with a different db name